# Cron "Mail Reports" Mail Delivery Issue

Tags: joomla

I would like to receive a report that I previously set up for cron operations as an e-mail. Cron reports successful in executing the menu, but no mail is received.

The system has no problem with sending mail. When I assign a person to an event, it sends an email. Or when I send test mail in Settings - Outbound Mail, there is no problem.

[image]

"No cron runs have been recorded." I get an error. Two questions arise here. Why "No cron runs have been recorded." It gives a warning and why doesn't it send the report as an e-mail.

My transactions.

I create a report and save it. ID is displayed in the report URL. In this example 47

[image]

I add my e-mail address to the e-mail field.

[image]

Then I edit the existing Cron.

[image]

I'm running it manually as I still haven't been able to accomplish the scheduled task. I look in the log, there are no errors.

[image]

But even though I try with different e-mail addresses, it does not send any e-mails. For this, I also tried options such as CVC, Print, PDF.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/ to create an entry in your system's cron to execute these jobs?  If so, how is that configured?

Comment: Is it only one email address in the to/cc field for the report or are you trying to email it to more than one recipient?

Comment: I only want to send to 1 recipient